# Get tweet by ID with Twitter::Net

Tags: perl, twitter

I have a most simple task: I try to read programmatically a tweet given its ID. For the access to the Twitter API, I use Perl's `Twitter::Net` API .

In lack of a clear documentation of which methods Twitter::Net provides (the docu is very verbose on the `search` method, as if that would be the only method of interest, but it doesn't even provide a list of all supported methods), I had to work with trial and error.

[Twitter's REST API doc](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1) says:

> `GET statuses/show/:id` - returns a single Tweet, specified by the id
>   parameter. The Tweet's author will also be embedded within the tweet.

I create a Twitter::Net instance, using my credentials and the `REST 1.1` trait,

```
my $nt = Net::Twitter->new(
  traits   =>   [ qw/API::RESTv1_1/ ],
  consumer_key => '...',
  consumer_secret => '...',
  access_token =>  '...',
  access_token_secret => '...',
  ssl => 1
  );
```

Now I tried

```
my $t = $nt->show( <tweet_id> );
```

with no success:

```
Tweets11.pm: Can't locate object method "show" via package "Net::Twitter_v4_01002_with__API_RESTv1_1__OAuth" at Tweets11.pm line 25.
```

Similar message with `statuses` instead of `show`.

How to afford this very simple task with Perl's `Twitter::Net`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the docs for [`Twitter::Net`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Twitter), the method you want is actually `show_status`:

> - `show_status`
> - `show_status(id)`
>
>   Parameters: id, trim_user, include_entities, include_my_retweet
>     Required: id
>
>   Returns a single status, specified by the id parameter. The status's author will be returned inline.
>     Returns: Status

Comment: I must have been blind to oversee this! Thanks - works as described!